# Interactive Message Templates for whatsApp not available in twilio

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-node

According to facebook dev
[docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/message-templates/interactive-message-templates#buttons) whatsApp provides 2 template.

1. call to action
2. Quick replies

After looking into twilio docs i did not find support for Interactive message Templates for [nodejs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/using-whatsapp-conversations).

> Is interactive Message Templates for whatsApp not available in twilio nodejs sdk ?
> If available can you provide a link thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is information on Twilio WhatsApp templates (which are used to initiate contact to the consumer). The Twilio WhatsApp sandbox has some default templates but you must define templates for Twilio WhatsApp enabled numbers.

[Send WhatsApp Notification Messages with Templates](https://www.instagram.com/reel/CI2G2h0DOSS/?igshid=1wieeqsexkulf)

The [Twilio API for WhatsApp now supports interactive message templates](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-whatsapp-quick-reply-buttons-for-more-engaging-customer-experiences). Check out [the documentation for using buttons in WhatsApp templates here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons).

Comment: Sir, i think you have given wrong link. Can you recheck please.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, once i link my whatsApp business account. I can create  interactive Message Templates and use them right ?

Comment: Correct - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039737753-Recommendations-and-best-practices-for-creating-WhatsApp-Message-Templates.

Comment: The [Twilio API for WhatsApp now supports interactive message templates](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-whatsapp-quick-reply-buttons-for-more-engaging-customer-experiences). Check out [the documentation for using buttons in WhatsApp templates here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons).

Comment: @philnash WhatsApp now supports interactive messages without using templates. Still waiting for solution providers like Twilio to implement this... I hope Facebook will open up their cloud-hosted API soon. See "Interactive Messages do not require templates or pre-approvals." over at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages

Comment: @sibbl you are right, all I can say is that Twilio currently supports interactive message templates, which is what the original question was asking about. Hopefully we can support interactive messages without templates too, but I don't know if or when that might be coming myself.